# Uppercase Gamma not appearing in mtpro2 package with fontspec, Baskerville, and XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mactex, mtpro

Please help with the stated problem. I can't get \Gamma command to render an upper case straight gamma greek letter. I am using TextPad on a MacTex distribution with mtpro2 lite and Baskerville font via fontspec. I also have utf8 symbols for use with spanish language. The command \varGamma works just fine and I thought it might be an issue with installing mtpro2 on OS X El Capitan but all other symbols work just fine, as far as I know.

```
\documentclass[12pt, noamssymb]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[xetex]{graphicx}                            
\usepackage{float}                       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}                    
\usepackage{amsmath}                 
            \let\hbar\relax              
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}                            
\usepackage{sectsty}                      
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{arydshln}               
\usepackage{pdflscape}      
\usepackage{fontspec}                   
\setmainfont{Baskerville}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
{\Gamma _{rx,wall}} \equiv \frac{{{K_{rx}}}}{{{K_{rx,sur}}}} \approx 1 + 1.26\frac{d}{B}\left[ {1 + \frac{d}{B}{{\left( {\frac{D}{d}} \right)}^{0.2}}{{\left( {\frac{B}{L}} \right)}^{0.5}}} \right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This gives [image: The upper case Gamma problem]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you shouldn't be using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex and definitely not in the same document as `\usepackage{fontspec} `

Comment: Are you working with MacTeX2015 or a still-older TeX distribution? I experience no problems with `\Gamma` when compiling your code under the MacTeX2016 versions of LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. Incidentally, you should definitely not be loading the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages.

Comment: With egreg's correction the issue was fixed although I still need to update. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 6):

If I reorganize the preamble like below, the `\Gamma` appears.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
  \let\hbar\relax
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskerville}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Gamma _{rx,\mathrm{wall}} \equiv \frac{K_{rx}}{K_{rx,\mathrm{sur}}} \approx
  1 + 1.26\frac{d}{B}\left[
   1 + \frac{d}{B}\left(\frac{D}{d}\right)^{0.2}\left( \frac{B}{L} \right)^{0.5}
  \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I removed `inputenc`, `fontenc` and `graphicx` (loaded by `adjustbox` with the `export` option). Also `pdflscape` isn't that useful with XeLaTeX, it might go with LuaLaTeX.

Surely you *don't* specify `xetex` for `graphicx`, never: it just limits code portability and is useless.

You have too many braces, also; I removed all the useless (and harmful, in some cases) ones. The `noamssymbols` option is unknown to every package you load.

If you load `float` for the `[H]` option, just don't use it.

[image]

Comment: egreg thanks alot, that fixed all issues. Had a real mess in there since I used to run latex in windows for the longest time. Thank You!